# Django order by issue when used Q filter with multiple order by and distinct

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, django-filter

I am working on a photos project where a user can **Download** or **Like** a photo (do other operations as well) . I have two models to track this information. Below are the models used (**Postgres** the database used).

```
# Photo model stores photos
# download_count, like_count is stored in the same model as well for easier querying
class Photo(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        download_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        views = GenericRelation(
            'Stat', related_name='photo_view',
            related_query_name='photo_view', null=True, blank=True)
        downloads = GenericRelation(
            'Stat', related_name='photo_download',
            related_query_name='photo_download', null=True, blank=True)
    
    
# Stat has generic relationship with photos. So that it can store any stats information
class Stat(models.Model):
        VIEW = 'V'
        DOWNLOAD = 'D'
        LIKE = 'L'
        STAT_TYPE = (
            (VIEW, 'View'),
            (DOWNLOAD, 'Download'),
            (LIKE, 'Like'),
        )
        user = models.ForeignKey(
            User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(
            ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
        object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        content_object = GenericForeignKey()
        stat_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STAT_TYPE, default=VIEW)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My requirement is fetch the **Photos that are popular this week**. The popularity score should consider the **likes count, download count**.

I had written below query to get the popular photos this week which checks the likes or downloads created this week.

```
# week number
current_week = date.today().isocalendar()[1]

photos = Photo.objects.filter(Q(likes__created_at__week=current_week) | Q(downloads__created_at__week=current_week))\
            .order_by('id', 'download_count', 'like_count')\
            .distinct('id')
```

**Problem:** With the above query, the result set is always ordered by **id** even though other fields are mentioned.

**Requirement:** The photos should be **ordered by sum of total likes and downloads** so that they will be sorted by popularity.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this considering the database performance.

Thank You

Comment: If you want to order by total likes and download why do you order by `'id'`? Is there any specific reason to include it? Since `id` is always unique it's always only going to sort by id. Have you linked into query annotations and aggregration in Django? I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Exelian I have mentioned the id in order by as it is used in .distinct('id'). If I remove it from order by, the query is not compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@biplove-lamichhane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10860596/biplove-lamichhane) for suggesting me annotate function. I could able to achive the desired response by using the below query

```
photos = Photo.objects.filter(is_active=True)\
                .filter(Q(likes__created_at__week=current_week) | Q(downloads__created_at__week=current_week))\
                .annotate(score=F('download_count') + F('like_count'))\
                .order_by('-score')\
                .distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) and [F object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for such cases:

```
photos = Photo.objects.filter().annotate(like_download=F('download_count') + F('like_count')).order_by('like_download').distinct()
```

Comment: Okay, but this query is not checking the duration. I want to fetch popular photos that has likes and downloads in this week.

Comment: Yes, coz I have just shown you the work of annotate and removed other parts to make it understandable.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have modified the query as below. It seems the results are fine. Could you verify it once?

 Photo.objects.filter(is_active=True)\
                .filter(Q(likes__created_at__week=current_week) | Q(downloads__created_at__week=current_week))\
                .annotate(score=F('download_count') + F('like_count'))\
                .order_by('-score')\
                .distinct()

Answer (score 1):

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

The result above will be ordered by pub_date descending, then by headline ascending. The negative sign in front of "-pub_date" indicates descending order.

So if you give `id`, it will be ordered by `id` first.

You can use `annotate` in your case.
Per-object summaries can be generated using the annotate() clause. When an annotate() clause is specified, each object in the QuerySet will be annotated with the specified values.